# Next lowest value in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `experience` 
WHERE  `reqexp` <>  '4793'
ORDER BY  'lvl' DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Here is what I want to do. I am making an online game for a client, and need to be able to use a mysql query with a random value, and find the level associated with that amount of experience. In this case, I need to find the next value lower than 4793 that already exists in the database so I can determine the players appropriate level. Any Ideas?

Comment: This is a programming question and belongs to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of ordering by `lvl` (which is incorrectly quoted with `'` single quotes instead of backquotes, and therefore treated as a string literal), you need to order by `reqexp DESC` and look for only values `< 4793`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `experience`
WHERE `reqexp` < 4793
ORDER BY `reqexp` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you still need to sub-order by `lvl`, then:

```
ORDER BY `reqexp` DESC, `lvl`
```